# How to sum values by value in other columns in pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Hi I am dealing with some data by using pandas.

I am facing a problem but here I'll try to simplify it.

Suppose I have a dataset looks like this:

```
      # Incidents            Place           Month
0          3                   A               1
1          5                   B               1
2          2                   C               2
3          2                   B               2
4          6                   C               3
5          3                   A               1
```

So I want to sum the # of incidents by the place, that is, I want to have a result like

```
P #
A 3 
B 7(5+2) 
C 8(2+6)
```

stored in a pandas DataFrame. I don't care about other columns at this point.

Next question is, now if I want to use the data in **Month** column as well, I'd like to have result looks like

```
P M  #
A 1  6(3+3)
B 1  5
B 2  2
C 2  2
C 3  6
```

How can I achieve these results in pandas? I have tried groupby and some other functions but I cannot reach the point...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   # Incidents Place  Month
0            3     A      1
1            5     B      1
2            2     C      2
3            2     B      2
4            6     C      3
5            3     A      1

In [36]: df.groupby('Place')['# Incidents'].sum().reset_index()
Out[36]:
  Place  # Incidents
0     A            6
1     B            7
2     C            8

In [37]: df.groupby(['Place', 'Month'])['# Incidents'].sum().reset_index()
Out[37]:
  Place  Month  # Incidents
0     A      1            6
1     B      1            5
2     B      2            2
3     C      2            2
4     C      3            6
```

Please find [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) a Pandas documentation with lots of examples.

Comment: I did read it but I think I prob missed something, anyway, I'll go through it again later, thank you very much.